# Facebook comment plugin in bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, facebook, twitter-bootstrap, facebook-social-plugins

For a simple website i am building i need the Facebook Social Plugins - Comments integrated.

It's pretty basic. A page loads (item.php) with the corresponding data from a mysql database.
I have created a FB app for the Social Plugins and added the code to the page. This works without problems, however... I want the comment-plugin to be shown in a modal window (Bootstrap) after the user has clicked the Comment button on the same page. (i.e: [This link - press comment button](http://www.espn.co.uk/f1/story/_/id/12626987/mercedes-driver-nico-rosberg-determined-rectify-f1-form-chinese-grand-prix))

The modal opens nicely but the comment-plugin is not shown.
When i check the code in i.e: Chrome inspector, the Facebook plugin seems to be loaded and is generating text and images. But for some reason, it will not show up inside my modal window.

I have added a "share" and a "like" button to see it those will show up, and both won't give any problems.

Anyone has an idea on how this fix this issue?

Here is a piece of the code:
Button:

```
<a class="btn btn-block btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#commentModal">Comments (<span class="fb-comments-count" data-href="<?php echo $config['paths']['siteURL']; ?>item.php?item=<?php echo $res['titel']; ?>"></span>)</a>
```

Modal window:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="commentModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="commentModal" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="false">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Comments for <?php echo $res['titel']; ?></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="fb-comments" data-href="<?php echo $config['paths']['siteURL']; ?>item.php?item=<?php echo $res['titel']; ?>" data-numposts="5" data-colorscheme="light"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The width of span of comment view is set to be 0 because it is hidden at first by bootstrap, and then after it is showed, the width is still 0 therefore you cannot see it. Maybe you can manually set the width I guess.

This is not a bug of facebook sdk. Facebook sdk has no idea what you gonna do with the span later. It can only render it in initial loading period. Maybe bootstrap can do something about this in their future version. But don't hope too much...

Comment: I have removed the bootstrap modal from the page and placed a fancybox2 box instead.
Maybe in a future version this will get solved. For now i have my problem fixed with another plugin.